# Authenticate desktop application to API server

Tags: authentication, security, desktop

Our Windows Application is deployed as an Exe file via ClickOnce, signed with a code-signing certificate.

We want to make sure that only the EXE (c#) can connect to the WebServer (IIS) The webserver hosts the RESTful APIs that are consumed by the windows executable.

I understand that i cannot send the code-signing certificate because i dont have the private key on the exe bytes.

The solution could be to buy a trusted third party certificate and embed it on the app?

I would prefer not to install the certificate on each computer using the app.

Is that scenario a good idea?
Is there a better way to authenticate the desktop app to prevent anything else from calling the APIs on the server?

Would it be oAuth2 a better solution for this problem, instead of dealing with certificates?

Thanks!